# How to replace RichTextEditor text without loosing the formatting in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, rich-text-editor

In my ActionScript code, I'm using a richTextEditor to do the following.

```
protected function createEmailTemplateContent(subRecord:String = null):void{
var index:int = emailTemplateContent.selection.beginIndex;
if(subRecord != null){
    emailTemplateContent.text = emailTemplateContent.text.substring(0,index) + '{[' + fieldTypeDD.selectedItem + '].[' + insertFieldDD.selectedItem.toString().substring(0,insertFieldDD.selectedItem.toString().indexOf('(+)')-1) +  '].[' + subRecord + ']}' + emailTemplateContent.text.substring(index,emailTemplateContent.text.length);
}else{
    emailTemplateContent.text = emailTemplateContent.text.substring(0,index) + '{[' + fieldTypeDD.selectedItem + '].[' + insertFieldDD.selectedItem + ']}' + emailTemplateContent.text.substring(index,emailTemplateContent.text.length);
}
}
```

The above method implements when the user selects an item from a drop down list. Then that particular item will be populated inside the text area of the rich text editor.

My issue is that if the user has already done some formatting (using the formatting options in RichTextEditor) on the text, that also get replaced when the user selects an item and populates the text area.

In this, 'emailTemplateContent' means the RichTextEditor. I have included my RichTextEditor code in the following.

```
<component:RichTextEditorWithAllControls id="emailTemplateContent" dropShadowVisible="false" creationComplete="emailTemplatesContentInit()" headerHeight="0" width="100%" height="100%" htmlText="@{emailTemplateObject.emailContent}" showControlBar="false" verticalScrollPolicy="auto"/>
```

I assume this happens because when I populate the 'text' value in the richTextEditor, the 'htmlText' value is also get replaced.

Does anyone know a way to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add screen shot showing the formatted text and what happens after you select an item from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

First store the concatenated text in a String and then replace it in the html text. Something like below

```
protected function createEmailTemplateContent(subRecord:String = null):void{
  var index:int = emailTemplateContent.selection.beginIndex;
  var newText:String;
  if(subRecord != null){
    newText = emailTemplateContent.text.substring(0,index) 
    + '{[' + fieldTypeDD.selectedItem + '].[' + insertFieldDD.selectedItem.toString().substring(0,insertFieldDD.selectedItem.toString().indexOf('(+)')-1) +  '].[' + subRecord + ']}' + emailTemplateContent.text.substring(index,emailTemplateContent.text.length);
  }else{
    newText = emailTemplateContent.text.substring(0,index) + '{[' + fieldTypeDD.selectedItem + '].[' + insertFieldDD.selectedItem + ']}' + emailTemplateContent.text.substring(index,emailTemplateContent.text.length);
  }
  emailTemplateContent.htmlText = emailTemplateContent.htmlText.replace(emailTemplateContent.text, newText);
}
```